# Making Android not respond to connecting headphones

Tags: bluetooth, audio, headphones

My android (Galaxy sII, CM9) has this thing where if I connect/disconnect headphones (either audio jack or bluetooth) it responds to it. (Like turns the song on or off.) I use Poweramp for music.

The idea is great but the execution is horrible. It tends to just turn on random audio files in my phone that I don't want to hear, or just switch songs arbitrarily, lose the point in a podcast that I'm at so I have to reopen the file and find the point again, etc.

How do I cancel any and all Android responses to connecting or disconnecting headphones? I don't want my phone to do anything when I connect or disconnect headphones.

Answer (score 1):

You can make this happen by going in poweramp settings->Headset/Bluetooth an uncheck 
Pause On Headset Disconnect and Resume on wired Headset and that should be it